# Create a new systemd service

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to create a new systemd service that controls wifi? I have created this service and enabled with "systemctl enable vswm" but looks like not working on startup. Any tips?

```
[Unit]
Description=vswm service
ConditionPathExists=/usr/local/bin/vswm

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vswm
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What errors are you getting please post them from `journalctl -xe | tail -20`

Answer (score 0):

what about `Type=oneshot`?

If that doesn't work: maybe you have to change ownership of the file to `root` as well.