# Run Resolution command on startup

Tags: startup, display-resolution

I know this Q.asked  million times.
but I need someone who gives me an easy tutorial...
Recently,I've changed my screen resolution and saved my resolution in
(/home/ma/resolution.sh)
and I need to run it every time I start my pc !
I've googled google for 2 hour and IDK NOTHING WORKED OR IT IS SUCH HARD FOR ME :D
First I've tried crontab -e and it doesn't work ! Second I've tried the startup application and it doesn't work ! (these two methods mostly I am doing something in a wrong way). What I am looking for is someone give me a full tutorial from zero ! I am beginner for this OS ... Any one types how to make this command (resolution.sh) that run every time I start my PC will help me
So, can anyone help me what to write in terminal every LITTLE BIT
AND
Thanks for help

Comment: Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! ([via](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run something at startup you should use systemd. It it is easy to setup a service in `/etc/systemd/system/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My personal program to start
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/full/path/to/my/program
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If you are doing graphics (e.g. x-windows like xrandr) you'd have to add this into your bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/yourUserName/.Xauthority
```

You have to adapt the path names...

Comment: so first  what should I do in terminal .I am a beginner as written upward

Comment: You copy that text into an editor of your choice and save that. Read the manual of how to activate a systemd service. It should help you to get to know your system better. You are free to search everywhere or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959168/create-a-new-systemd-service).

Comment: Thanks for you time @kanehekili . I need to understand something from you !  Give me an Editor example and my service is Resolution.sh ..Can you type for me an example of the service form ? And in Systemd for my case I need to Enable or to Activate Systemd ?? I will really a appreciate that !

Comment: Oh okay I've understood what you mean by bash and editor and systemd services ...Thanks alot 

Answer (score 0):

**~/.bashrc** is a bash file which runs whenever your Ubuntu boots up. Try putting your desired command at the end of this bash file and see the magic. Not only this method is concise and uses only a single command to be placed inside a ready-made file, this also is a pretty good file if you want to read anything about bash files which run on startup and also pretty easy to use.